# Opengl SOIL textureCoords not recognizing

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, soil

I'm writing my program, that draws a quad with a texture. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #define GLEW_STATIC
 #include <GL/glew.h>
 #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
 #include <SOIL.h>
 #include <math.h>

 extern const char* VertexShaderCode;
 extern const char* FragmentShaderCode;




 int main()
 {
    glfwInit();
glewInit();
//initialize glew
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);

int width = 1920, height = 1080;

glViewport(0, 0, width, height);


GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Opengl program", NULL, NULL);
glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
if (!window)
{
    printf("Someting is wrong with window");
}
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
{
    printf("Something is wrong with glew");
}


/*GLfloat vertecies[] = {
    0.75f, 0.75f, 0.0f, //0
    0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, //1
    -0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, //2
    -0.75f, 0.75f, 0.0f, //3
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, //0
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, //1
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, //2
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, //3
};

GLuint index[] =
{
    0,4,1,
    4,1,5,
    5,1,2,
    6,2,5,
    2,6,3,
    6,7,3,
    3,7,4,
    3,4,0
};*/

GLfloat vertecies[] = {
    //vertices              colors
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,     1.0f, 1.0f,     // Top Right
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f,       // Bottom Right
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,     0.0f, 0.0f,     // Bottom Left
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f       // Top Left 
};

GLuint index[] =
{
    0,1,3,
    1,2,3
};

GLfloat texCoords[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f,  // Lower-left corner  
    1.0f, 0.0f,  // Lower-right corner
    0.5f, 1.0f   // Top-center corner
};


glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

int widthText, heightText;
unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image("container.jpg", &widthText, &heightText, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);

GLuint texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, widthText, heightText, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

SOIL_free_image_data(image);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);











glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);

GLuint EBO;
glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(index), index, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLuint VAO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);

GLuint VBO;
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertecies), vertecies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(index), index, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
// Color attribute
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(6 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

glBindVertexArray(0);


const char* adapter[1];
GLuint vertexShaderID;
vertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
adapter[0] = VertexShaderCode;
glShaderSource(vertexShaderID, 1, adapter, 0);
glCompileShader(vertexShaderID);

GLint success;
GLchar infoLog[512];
glGetShaderiv(vertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
if (!success)
{
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShaderID, 512, NULL, infoLog);
    printf("ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED %s\n", infoLog);
}

//declare fragment shader
GLuint fragmentShaderID;
//create fragment shader
fragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
//set fragment shader source
adapter[0] = FragmentShaderCode;
glShaderSource(fragmentShaderID, 1, adapter, 0);
//compile fragment shader
glCompileShader(fragmentShaderID);


//declare a shader program
GLuint shaderProgram;
shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
//attach haders to the program
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShaderID);
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShaderID);
//link program
glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
glUseProgram(shaderProgram);


//rendering
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glfwPollEvents();

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    //glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    //glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}
glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
glfwTerminate();
return 0;
```

}

The vertex attrib array is not setting texture vertex input as my third input. Can anyone see, whyt am I doing wrong? Oh and here's my shader code:

```
const char* VertexShaderCode =
 "#version 330 core\r\n"
 ""
 "layout(location=0) in vec3 position;"
 "layout(location=1) in vec3 color;"
 "layout(location=2) in vec2 textCoord;"
 ""
 "out vec2 TextCoord;"
 ""
 ""
 "out vec3 theColor;"
 ""
 "void main()"
 "{"
 "  gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);"
 "  theColor = color;"
 "  TextCoord = textCoord;"
 "}";

 const char* FragmentShaderCode =
 "#version 330 core\r\n"
 ""
 "in vec3 theColor;"
 "in vec2 TexCoord;"
 ""
 "uniform sampler2D ourTexture;"
 ""
 ""
 ""
 "out vec4 color;"
 "" 
 "void main()"
 "{"
 "  color = texture(ourTexture, TexCoord);"
 "}";
```

Help.

Answer (score 2):

The variable is called `out vec2 TextCoord` in the vertex shader, but `in vec2 TexCoord;` in the fragment shader (note the additional t in the vertex shader).

You are only checking the compile status of the vertex shader, but not the compile status of the fragment shader or the link status of the program.

Comment: Ok I'll edit the code and see what errors are coming out the fragment shader code

Comment: It worken when I added those "t"s in the fragment shader. Thanks